# Как осуществить поиск значение в определенной колонки с использование datagrid,БД

Tags: wpf, postgresql, datagrid

Хочу осуществить поиск значения в определенном столбце (ввод осуществляю с помощью textBox), но когда ввожу значение которое нужно найти, появляется чистый DataGrid и все. Если есть варианты альтернативного кода, то тоже буду благодарен.

```
private void textBoxFilterName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM \"Employee\" WHERE name ILIKE @searchTerm";
            using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, DataBase.Connection()))
            {
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchTerm", "%" + textBoxFilterName.Text + "%");
                 using (NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command))
                 {
                     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                     adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                     dataGridEmployeeTable.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
                 }
            }
        }
```